# A confusion about single slit diffraction

Tags: optics

I am studying wave optics at home. Yesterday I came across a diagram depicting single slit diffraction experiment of light, where they placed a convex lens. I could not understand the purpose of this convex lens.[image]

Comment: The convex lens in used to focus the rays into a point. It seems like Fraunhoffer diffraction, so the image is effectively at infinity. But here you need image at a finite distance. Something like that. I don't exactly remember, and I may be wrong. Sorry.

Comment: would interference on the screen occur without this convex lens?

Comment: Practically, no. It would, but at infinity. That would be more than the coherence length of any practical source, so theoretically answer is Yes.